# Java definitions: Label, Token

Tags: java, token, definitions

I wrote this:

```
(fitness>g.fitness) ? return 1 : return -1;
```

and received the following error:

Syntax error on tokens, label expected instead.

Can anyone explain what tokens and labels are in this context?

Edit: Thanks for fixing my code, but could you explain anyway what tokens and labels are, for future reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tokens are the individual characters and strings which have some kind of meaning.

Tokens, as defined in [Chapter 3: Lexical Structure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html) of [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html), are:

> identifiers (§3.8), keywords (§3.9),
>   literals (§3.10), separators (§3.11),
>   and operators (§3.12) of the syntactic
>   grammar.

The tokens in the given line are:

```
"(", "fitness", ">", "g.fitness", ")", "?", "return", "1", ":", "return", "-1", ";"
```

(Whitespace also counts, but I've omitted them from the above.)

---

Labels in Java are used for control of flow in a program, and is an identifier, followed by a colon.

An example of a label would be `hello:`.

Labels are used in conjunction with `continue` and `break` statements, to specify which control structure to `continue` or `break` to.

There is more information on Labeled Statements in [Section 14.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.7) of [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

---

The problem here is with the `return` statement:

```
(fitness>g.fitness) ? return 1 : return -1;
                      ^^^^^^
```

There is a `:` immediately following the `return 1`, which makes the compiler think that there is supposed to be a label there.

However, the `return 1` is a statement in itself, therefore, there is no label identifier there, so the compiler is complaining that it was expecting an label, but it was not able to find a properly formed label.

```
(fitness>g.fitness) ?  return 1   :   return -1;
                       ^^^^^^^^   ^
                      statement   label without an identifier
```

Answer (score 5):

Return is a statement and ?: needs expressions and so it is not accepted.

```
return (fitness > g.fitness) ? 1 : -1;
```

is probably what you want.

When parsing the code is first split so that it is easier to understand, these units are called tokens. I guess label refers to one language construct that happens to be the first possible one in a statement.

To understand how the parser decides to give that error message would require digging into the parser. Giving good error messages from parser is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do :

```
return (fitness>g.fitness) ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler is telling you that since there is a colon in your code it thinks that you are trying to declare a [label statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), but it can't parse it because your syntax is incorrect.